# Change a ClassName dynamically in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I wanna change a class dynamically and this is the component:

```
import classes from "./Board.module.css"

const Card = (props) => {
  const itemClass =
    "card" + (props.item.stat ? " active " + props.item.stat : "");
    console.log(itemClass);
  return (
    <div className={classes.itemClass} onClick={() => props.clickHandler(props.id)}>
      <label>{props.item.content}</label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

itemClass is a nameclass i want to change dynamicly
and that is the css file:

```
.card{
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    animation: 1s hideCard linear;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}


.card.wrong{
    background-color: red;

}
.card.correct{
    background-color: green;
}
.card.active{
    transform: rotateY(0);
}

.card.active label{
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

But I can seem to change the class name
only if I call classes.card it works but anytime I can't change to other classes in CSS
Hope someone can help me, please!
Thank you!

Change a class name dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap div tag with another and add card class to that and  simply add with condition in className of div tag

something like this :

```
     <div className={classes.card}>
        <div className={props.item.stat ? classes.active ? ''} onClick={() => props.clickHandler(props.id)}>
          <label>{props.item.content}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and change active class styles from this :

```
.card.active{
    transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

to this :

```
.card .active{
    transform: rotateY(0);
}
```